# Finding a base & dimension for a space which is span of a single matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a base & dimensions for the space $S$: $$S=\operatorname{span}(A)$$ $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-10  &-4  &5 \\ 
1 &-10  &-2  &5 \\ 
4 &-40  &-19  &19 \\ 
-1 &10  &11  &-4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

What am I missing? Isn't the dimension=1 and A would be the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S=span(A)=\{tA: t \in \mathbb R\}$, hence $ \dim S=1$ and a basis of $S$ is $\{A\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question refers to the span of the rowvectors; I've seen this notation before. So what you are asked to do is to find the dimension and basis of the image of $A$ understood as the linear transformation $$ x \mapsto Ax,$$ which is just the span of the row vectors of your matrix in $\mathbb{R}^4$.